# How to access the properties in nested Objects in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have 5 divs and among these I want the center div to be to be activated by default (appear a bit large and and have a paragraph inside it to be shown) while the 4 other remains inactive (smaller in size and paragraph hidden).

I defined my nested object as below, following a youtube tutorial:

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState({
  activeDiv: null,
  cardData: [
    {
      id: 1,
      iconTitle: faRocket,
      heading: "DevOps engineers",
      paragraph:"",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      iconTitle: faCodeBranch,
      heading: "Data scientists",
      paragraph:"B",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      iconTitle: faGear,
      heading: "Software engineers",
      paragraph:"",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      iconTitle: faHeadset,
      heading: "Support teams",
      paragraph:"",
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      iconTitle: faUsers,
      heading: "Engineering leaders",
      paragraph:"",
    },
  ],
});
```

Then I have this snippet to render the component:

```
<div>
  {selected.cardData.map((object, index) => (
    <div
      key={index}
      className={
        selected.cardData.id === index
          ? "organizationalfeature-content-stackoverflow-organization-strength-card-open"
          : "organizationalfeature-content-stackoverflow-organization-strength-card"
      }
      onClick={() => {
        activateDiv(index, selected.cardData.id);
      }}
    >
      <FontAwesomeIcon
        icon={object.iconTitle}
        className="fontawesome-icons"
      />
      <h2>{object.heading}</h2>
      <p
        className={
          selected.cardData.id === index
            ? "active-div-paragraph"
            : "inactive-div-paragraph"
        }
      >
        {object.paragraph}
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I console logged to see if there was any error in comparison with a function as:

```
function activateDiv(index, id) {
  console.log(index); //can get a value
  console.log(id); // is undefined
  setSelected({ ...selected, activeDiv: selected.cardData[index] });
  console.log(setSelected); //gives an error as:
}
```

The error:
`ƒ dispatchSetState(fiber, queue, action) { { if (typeof arguments[3] === 'function') { error("State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the " + 'sec…`

I think the problem is here in this lines:
`selected.cardData.id === index`
The conditional css is not taking effect as the comparision is between and undefined and numeric values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `object` to `selected.activeDiv` and compare the `selected.activeDiv.id` with the `object.id` to indicate which div is activated.

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

const cardData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        heading: "DevOps engineers",
        paragraph: "",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        heading: "Data scientists",
        paragraph: "B",
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        heading: "Software engineers",
        paragraph: "",
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        heading: "Support teams",
        paragraph: "",
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        heading: "Engineering leaders",
        paragraph: "",
    },
];

export default function App() {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState({
        activeDiv: cardData[2],
        cardData,
    });

    function activateDiv(object) {
        console.log(object);
        setSelected({ ...selected, activeDiv: object });
    }

    console.log(selected.activeDiv);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            {selected.cardData.map((object, index) => {
                return (
                    <div
                        key={index}
                        className={
                            selected.activeDiv?.id === object.id
                                ? "organizationalfeature-content-stackoverflow-organization-strength-card-open"
                                : "organizationalfeature-content-stackoverflow-organization-strength-card"
                        }
                        onClick={() => {
                            activateDiv(object);
                        }}>
                        <h2>
                            {object.heading} {selected.activeDiv?.id === object.id && <i>(activated)</i>}
                        </h2>
                        <p className={selected.activeDiv?.id === object.id ? "active-div-paragraph" : "inactive-div-paragraph"}>{object.paragraph}</p>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

After clicking the fifth div, the HTML elements and their class attributes:

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class="organizationalfeature-content-stackoverflow-organization-strength-card">
    <h2>DevOps engineers</h2>
    <p class="inactive-div-paragraph"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="organizationalfeature-content-stackoverflow-organization-strength-card">
    <h2>Data scientists</h2>
    <p class="inactive-div-paragraph">B</p>
  </div>
  <div class="organizationalfeature-content-stackoverflow-organization-strength-card">
    <h2>Software engineers</h2>
    <p class="inactive-div-paragraph"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="organizationalfeature-content-stackoverflow-organization-strength-card">
    <h2>Support teams</h2>
    <p class="inactive-div-paragraph"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="organizationalfeature-content-stackoverflow-organization-strength-card-open">
    <h2>Engineering leaders</h2>
    <p class="active-div-paragraph"></p>
  </div>
</div>;
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-77086626-dqpr8x)

Comment: thanks for the soultion. I tried to understand the mechanics, but i couldn't. could you explain a bit with the code flow. also, it doesn't completely work. cannot leave activeDiv as null, as it gives error. I just give it a random numeric value and it does work well while clicking a div. but still the default activeDiv cannot be set with this solution as well.

Comment: @BibekBhattarai Updated answer, the third div will be activated by default.

Comment: ok i got it. also, i found the way to have the initial default activeDiv. Its was as easy as to make the activeDiv as an object and have the property of the one we want to be default among the 5.

Comment: no no, it wont be by default. if the activeDiv is null, there will be error. It needs to be used as object as
'activeDiv: {
id: 3,
heading: "value",
....
}